# How to group rows together based on their column value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon', 'Falcon','Parrot', 'Parakeet'],
                   'Color':  ['Black', 'White', 'Green','Green'],
                   'Native': ['Americas','Africa','Americas','Asia'],
                   'Speed':  ['100 kmph','120 kmph','17 kmph','17 kmph']})
```

[image: df]

I am trying to group all the rows based on the Animal and Color here. So my target data frame would be

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Animal': ['Falcon','Parrot', 'Parakeet','Falcon'],
                   'Color':  ['Black', 'Green','Green', 'White'],
                   'Native': ['Americas','Africa','Asia','Americas'],
                   'Speed':  ['100 kmph','17 kmph','17 kmph','120 kmph']})
```

[image: df2]

How do I sort the data frame which multiple rows sorted by a same columnar values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just do `sort_values`

```
df = df.sort_values(['Color','Animal'])
Out[635]: 
     Animal  Color    Native     Speed
0    Falcon  Black  Americas  100 kmph
3  Parakeet  Green      Asia   17 kmph
2    Parrot  Green  Americas   17 kmph
1    Falcon  White    Africa  120 kmph
```